# Exercise 15, Section 17 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Show that $T_1$ axiom is equivalent to the condition that for each pair of points of $X$, each has a neighbourhood not containing the other.

I rephrase this exercise to my taste.

> Topological space $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ satisfy $T_1$ axiom $\iff$ $\forall x_1,x_2\in X,x_1 \neq x_2$ there exists an open set $U_1$ such that $x_1 \in U_1$ but $x_2 \not\in U_1$, and there exists an open set $U_2$ such that $x_2 \in U_2$ but $x_1 \not\in U_2$.

**My attempt:** ($\Rightarrow$) Suppose finite sets are closed in $X$. Let $x,y \in X$ such that $x\neq y$. Since $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ is closed in $X$, we have $X-\{x\} \in \mathcal{T}_X$ and $X-\{y\}\in \mathcal{T}_X$. So $\exists X-\{x\}\in \mathcal{T}_X$ such that $y \in  X- \{x\}$ and $x\notin X-\{x\}$. $\exists X-\{y\}\in \mathcal{T}_X$ such that $x \in  X- \{y\}$ and $y\notin X-\{y\}$.

($\Leftarrow$) It is suffices to show singleton sets are closed. fix $x\in X$. Let $y\in X$ such that $y\neq x$. $\exists U_y\in \mathcal{T}_{X}$ such that $y\in U_y$ and $x\notin U_y$. So $U_y \cap \{x\} = \phi$. By theorem 17.5, $y\notin \overline{ \{x\} }$(Note $U_y$is the neighbourhood of y). Thus $\overline{ \{x\} }= \{x\}$, $\{x\}$ is closed. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: I don't have the book, so I don't know how Munkres defines $T_1$; I take it the definition is "finite sets are closed" (because the definition I remember from my topology class was precisely the condition you  are trying to prove "equivalent"  to $T_1$). If so, this looks  right, but I would add some words of explanation at the end of the second part; it looks like  a bit of a jump from $y\notin\overline{\{x\}}$ to $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}$ (though I can fill the gaps). Equivalently, you can consider $\cap_{y\in X}(X\setminus U_y)$, which is closed, and show  it only contains $x$.

Comment: The rephrasing is fine, and is in most texts the standard definition for $T_1$ (but even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) uses the "words-version" of the definition.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yeah. I agree that was a bit of a jump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is in essence correct. Maybe some notational improvement and added or alternate reasoning wouldn't hurt, e.g. in my edited version:

Suppose finite sets are closed. Let $x_1,x_2 \in X$ be such that $x_1 \neq x_2$. Then $U_2:= X-\{x_1\}$ is open as $\{x_1\}$ is closed, and likewise $U_1:=X-\{x_2\}$ is open. As $x_1 \notin U_2,x_2 \in U_2$ and $x_2 \in U_2, x_1 \notin U_2$, your reformulated version is satisfied indeed. (using the same variable names is clearer IMO)

It suffices to show that singleton sets are closed (being closed is preserved by finite unions and a finite set is a finite union of singletons). Suppose that $\{x\}$ is not closed for some $x \in X$. This means that for some $y \neq x$ we have $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$. By 17.5 this means that **every** neighbourhood of $y$ intersects $x$ and this directly contradicts the $T_1$ reformulation for the pair $x,y$. So $\{x\}$ is closed and we're done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Your proofs are always slick.

Comment: @user264745 not always. But I’ve seen many good examples. You learn by good teachers and good books.